# Sci-fi movie (or TV series?) where a few teenagers were running along a beach and one of them fell into a tunnel

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I remember watching a movie (or TV series?) when I was a kid, around 1990-2000. It's sci-fi. The scene I remember was that a few teenagers were running on a beach, then one of them (a male) fell into a tunnel.

Another detail of which I'm not so sure: the tunnel was like half-transparent.

The scene was colored, I watched it on TV.

Can anyone help me to identify it? Apologies that I can't provide more details.

Comment: What could be seen through the walls of this transparent tunnel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a 100% match, but could you be thinking of [the first episode of the second iteration of *The Tomorrow People*](https://thetomorrowpeople.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tomorrow_People_(1990s_Series_serial))?

> A young man, Adam Newman, has been washed up on a beach on an island. Exploring, he finds mysterious stone objects buried in the sand. He clears a portal, which opens up and sucks him down a shaft into a futuristic spaceship.

### "The Tomorrow People" aka "Origin Story"

Comment: They've rebooted it twice, so it's also possible that they replicated this scene in later versions.

Comment: The 1990s version of The Tomorrow People was the second iteration, not the first.

Comment: Ah, so noted. I got confused. I think i watched the third one on Nickelodeon.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Do you mind if I edit the answer to clarify it was the second iteration?

Comment: No problem. I thought i did that last night.

Comment: Another example of embarrasingly bad British TV from script to production and everything in between.